# Issues compiling mediapipe with pyinstaller on macos

Tags: python, build, pyinstaller, mediapipe

I have issues compiling a project with mediapipe via pyinstaller on macos

so far I tried:

```
pyinstaller  --windowed --noconsole pose_edge.py

pyinstaller  --onefile --windowed --noconsole pose_edge.py

pyinstaller --noconsole pose_edge.py
```

The .app does not open, and if I try the unix exec, I get

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pose_edge.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "mediapipe/python/solutions/selfie_segmentation.py", line 54, in __init__
  File "mediapipe/python/solution_base.py", line 229, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: The path does not exist.
[36342] Failed to execute script pose_edge
```

I work with conda, my env is in python 3.8, mediapipe 0.8.5 and OSX 10.15.7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this issue too and just figured it out a few minutes ago -- so far, I'm getting around it the manual way, but I'm sure there's an idiomatic way to do it in pyinstaller using the spec file and the data imports. For this answer, I'm assuming you're not using the `--onefile` option for pyinstaller, but rather creating the binary in a single folder.

That said, the answer is to `cp -r` the modules directory from your mediapipe installed in the virtual environment (or wherever you installed the initial mediapipe package, e.g. /virtualenvs/pose_record-2bkqEH7-/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mediapipe/modules) into your `dist/main/mediapipe` directory. This will enable your bundled mediapipe library to access the binarypb files which I believe contain the graphs and weights for the pose detection algorithm.

**UPDATE:** I have figured out a more idiomatic pyinstaller way of getting it to run. In the `.spec` file generated by pyinstaller, you're able to automatically add files in the following way:

At the top of the file, under the `block_cipher = None`, add the following function:

```py
def get_mediapipe_path():
    import mediapipe
    mediapipe_path = mediapipe.__path__[0]
    return mediapipe_path
```

Then, after the following lines:

```py
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

add the following lines which utilize the [native Tree class to create a TOC for the binary](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes):

```py
mediapipe_tree = Tree(get_mediapipe_path(), prefix='mediapipe', excludes=["*.pyc"])
a.datas += mediapipe_tree
a.binaries = filter(lambda x: 'mediapipe' not in x[0], a.binaries)
```

Once added, you can run the compile command from the CLI, e.g.:
`pipenv run pyinstaller --debug=all main.spec --windowed --onefile`

This allowed me to build an executable that functioned for mediapipe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and yeah I put all mediapipe dir from miniconda to the dir in dist/pose_edge/, When I run the unix bin it works ! I just need to know how to get the .app bundle with this technique (is it possible to rerender it from the bin file ?), thanks in advance

Comment: @Felox Frankly, I wish I could take credit for this (beyond my Google-fu working), but [haim gelfenbeyn](https://haim.dev/posts/2020-08-08-python-macos-app/) wrote a phenomenal post about how to both build a .app bundle, as well as how to notarize it. Hope this helps!


tl;dr: you need to run `--onefile --windowed`, but there are some important [additional caveats/lines to add to your specfile](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-options-for-a-mac-os-x-bundle) in order for the .app bundle to get built.

Answer (score 2):

If anybody needs to manage this issue on Windows(maybe you can try this on MAC or Linux) you can follow these steps which have given a solution for me:

- Go your local Python site-packages(generally it's in C:/Users/YourUserName/AppData/Local/Python38/Lib/site-packages) and find the mediapipe module(folder) in it.
- Open the mediapipe>python>solution_base.py file.
- Edit the solution_base.py file with these given variables:

> Delete this line(at 261) --> root_path = os.sep.join(os.path.abspath(**file**).split(os.sep)[:-3])

Instead of this line, we will create our root_path:

> root_path = "C:\\Users\YourUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\Lib\\site-packages"

Copy and paste this line. **Change your user name!**

The .exe output may need run as administrator!

In this way you could solve your root_path problem.

You dont need to use any PyInstaller configuration. Just type:

> PyInstaller yourscriptname.py --onefile