# How do i make .exe from .py with mediapipe module installed?

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, exe, mediapipe

Ok, so. I know how to make an .exe from .py, but when mediapipe module is present in the code, the .exe will give me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9zDR.png). It says "The path does not exist.", but it does. [Here is the path code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scZ6Z.png), and [Here is the path itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WrVE.png). Here is how to replicate this error: 1.copy my main.py  2.pip instal cv2, mediapipe and pyinstaller  3.run pyinstaller  4.copy mediapipe files to the same folder as main.exe 5.run main.exe Please help me, I have been trying to fix this for 8 hours straight and i just can't keep going. Any help is welcome. Thank you all in advance!

main.py:

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    results = hands.process(imgRGB)

    if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
        for handLms in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms, mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
            for id, lm in enumerate(handLms.landmark):
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 7, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, str(id), (cx+10,cy+10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, (0,0,0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Maybe similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67986441/18667225 ?

Answer (score 0):

1.try making the mediapipe source files in same directory before building
2.if the above doesnt work use pyinstallers --runtime-hook passing the mediapipe compiled module i.e pyc

Answer (score 0):

use pyinstaller adding --import argumeng and pass "mediapipe", this will import the library and embed it to the executable