# How do i solve that the .exe file of my project doesn't recognizes the mediapipe hand module

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, mediapipe

I converted a python file(simple handtracking with mediapipe nothing special) into a .exe file with pyinstaller. Now I wanted to test it, however, I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "trackinghand.py", line 19, in <module> 
File "mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in __init__ 
File "mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 271, in __init__ 

FileNotFoundError: The path does not exist. 
[19688] Failed to execute script 'trackinghand' due to unhandled exception!
```

How do i fix that ?

I've already searched for `non-unicode` characters in the path of the project -> nothing I've also tried using the `--hidden-import` tag but it didn't work either... Any Ideas I really need this to work

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67986441/9705687)?